# Multiple concurrent connections with Vertx

Tags: vert.x

I'm trying to build a web application that should be able to handle at least 15000 rps. Some of the optimizations I have done is increase the worker pool size to 20 and set an accept back log to 25000. Since I have set my worker pool size to 20; wil this help with the the blocking piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

A worker pool size of 20 seems to be [the default](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/9d3fc43adc185d3de257165d14c1c6c5c43066d2/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/VertxOptions.java#L45).

I believe the important question in your case is how long do you expect each request to run. On my side, I expect to have thousands of short-lived requests, each with a payload size of about 5-10KB. All of these will be blocking, because of a blocking database driver I use at the moment. I have increased the default worker pool size to 40 and I have explicitly set my deploy vertical instances using the following formulae:

```
final int instances = Math.min(Math.max(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() / 2, 1), 2);
```

A test run of 500 simultaneous clients running for 60 seconds, on a vert.x server doing nothing but blocking calls, produced an average of 6 failed requests out of 11089. My test payload in this case was ~28KB.

Of course, from experience I know that running my software in production would often produce results that I have not anticipated. Thus, the important thing in my case is to have good atomicity rules in place, so that I don't get half-baked or corrupted data in the database.

Comment: Two questions:
1. What the motivation behind that formula? For example: if my CPU has 2 cores; the above formula will set the number of instances to 1. Wouldn't that be under utilized?

2. How did you test the simultaneous client requests?